# What happens when I have zero Cool?

Tags: bubblegumshoe

Bubblegumshoe 68, "Effects of Cool Damage," has entries labelled like this:

> **Cool 5 to 0:** [mechanical effects] 
>   **Cool 0 to -5:** [mechanical effects] 
>   **Cool -6 to -10:** [mechanical effects] 
>   **Cool worse than -10:** [mechanical effects]

The first two entries seem to overlap; which effects do I suffer when I have zero Cool points?

Comment: Can you include the mechanical effects for 5 to 0 and 0 to -5? That might give us more insight into whether we are dealing with a continuous or discontinuous piece-wise function.

Comment: @GraemeRock I could, but I've already included the specific wording I'm concerned about and [providing more of the text will encourage people to answer despite being unfamiliar with the system](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/5512/4398).

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a legitimate bug, since the two possibilities for 0 Cool seem exclusive. Evil Hat has a [Bubblegumshoe Downloads](http://www.evilhat.com/home/bubblegumshoe-downloads/) page with a link to errata, but this doesn't appear there. I wasn't able to find another instance of the damage table in the rules or the charts and forms, either. You may have to contact Evil Hat or something.

Answer (score -1):

In other Gumshoe games you can have a 0 Health & Stability without penalties. So I bet Cool would work that way.

Comment: There are already penalties in the 5-0 range, so that analogy doesn't seem like it flies.